# How to use biglm with more than 2^31 observations

Tags: r, bigdata

I am working with a large set of data that contains more than 2^31 observations. The actual number of observations is close to 3.5 billion observations.

I am using the R package "biglm" to run a regression with approximately 70 predictors. I read in the data one million rows at a time and update the regression results. The data have been saved in the ffdf format using the R library "ffdf" to load quickly and avoid using up all my RAM.

Here is the basic outline of the code I am using:

```
library(ff,ffbase,biglm)
load.ffdf(dir='home')

dim(data) #the ffdf contains about 70 predictors and 3.5 billion rows

chunk_1 <- data[1:1000000,]
rest_of_data <- data[1000000:nrow(data),]

# Running biglm for first chunk
b <- biglm(y~x1+x2+...+x70, chunk_1)

chunks <- ceiling((nrow(rest_of_data)/1000000)

# Updating biglm results by iterating through the rest of the data chunks
for (i in seq(1,chunks)){
      start <- 1+((i-1))*1000000
      end <- min(i*1000000,nrow(d))
      d_chunk <- d[start:end,]
      b<-update(b,d_chunk)
}
```

The results look great and everything is running smoothly until the cumulative number of observations from updating the model with each chunk of the data exceeds 2^31 observations. Then, I get an error that reads

```
In object$n + NROW(mm) : NAs produced by integer overflow
```

How do I get around this overflow issue? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: @DavidArenburg I am currently using a 64-bit system, and I was using R 3.4.0. I was still running into the integer overflow problem, however.

Comment: Do you really have a 1.8TB dataset?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe that I have found the source of the issue in the biglm code.

The number of observations (`n`) is stored as an integer, which [has a max value](https://www.r-bloggers.com/r-in-a-64-bit-world/) of `2^31 - 1`.

The `numeric` type is not subject to this limit, and, as far as I can tell, can be used instead of integers to store `n`.

[Here is a commit on github](https://github.com/emckay/biglm/commit/cc036a606567c2db4e749ad04afe0840702b987d) showing how to fix this problem with one additional line of code that converts the integer `n` to a `numeric`. As the model is updated, the number of rows in the new batch is added to the old `n`, so the type of `n` remains `numeric`.

I was able to reproduce the error described in this question and verify that my fix works with this code:

(WARNING: This consumes a large amount of memory, consider doing more iterations with a smaller array if you have tight memory constraints)

```
library(biglm)
df = as.data.frame(replicate(3, rnorm(10000000)))
a = biglm(V1 ~ V2 + V3, df)
for (i in 1:300) {
    a = update(a, df)
}
print(summary(a))
```

In the original biglm library, this code outputs:

```
Large data regression model: biglm(ff, df)
Sample size =  NA 
              Coef (95% CI) SE  p
(Intercept) -1e-04   NA  NA NA NA
V2          -1e-04   NA  NA NA NA
V3          -2e-04   NA  NA NA NA
```

My patched version outputs:

```
Large data regression model: biglm(V1 ~ V2 + V3, df)
Sample size =  3.01e+09 
              Coef   (95%    CI) SE p
(Intercept) -3e-04 -3e-04 -3e-04  0 0
V2          -2e-04 -2e-04 -1e-04  0 0
V3           3e-04  3e-04  3e-04  0 0
```

The SE and p values are non-zero, just rounded in the output above.

I am fairly new to the R ecosystem, so I would appreciate it if someone could tell me how to submit this patch so that it can be reviewed by the original author and eventually included in the upstream package.

Comment: Unfortunately the biglm package looks to be abandoned; the last release was 4 years ago. Fortunately since it's open source, anyone can take your change and compile it on their own system (+1).

Comment: Wow, this is great. Thank you very much for your help! This means a lot to me, and I hope it can be helpful to others working with big data :)

Comment: not automated, but a faster solution would be to use `biglm <- edit(biglm)` and add in your fix `rval$n<-as.numeric(rval$n)` right after `rval <- list(...)`

Comment: @rawr does that "permanently" change my local version of the package or would I have to do that each time I start a new R session?

Comment: yes, you would have to do it each time.. you could `rm(biglm)` after the edit to get back the original, or re-edit. it's just faster than making another branch and having to re-install each time. and even tho you edit and save your own, the function still thinks it is in the package, so there won't be any scoping or "objects not found" issues

Comment: Not sure if that approach will work for me then. I usually write the R programs and run them via the command line rather than in an interactive session. Thanks though! That would have helped me when I was trying to debug this.